# ERROR [layer.TileLayer] - Unable to write image tile to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, geoserver

I am using a standalone Geowebcache 1.5.2

My geowebcache points to Geoserver 2.5 and gets the values from there.

Typically when i expose a .tiff file through geowebcache then i get the following error at random occasions.

```
"javax.imageio.IIOException: The provided image cannot be encoded using: com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.png.CLibPNGImageWriter"
```

Please advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked this issue ? This could be your problem.
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOT-4540

Comment: Thank you for the response mate. I am using Java 1.7, Do you think that can be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so if you're in the same case that the GEOT issue it seems related to the number of colors of the image. Try to use images with a palette color depth of at least 16 colors. You can also try to upgrade to the latest version as this problem has been fixed since then.